# Processing after the request was completed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have one API endpoint that needs to return to the caller as soon as possible. It currently returns under 1ms. If, however, I log some stuff to the database it now takes closer to 10ms.

How would you approach completing the request and then doing some kind of processing after the request was completed? I tried with Response.Body.Flush(), but that doesn't complete the request and it still takes the full 10ms. It looks like it's sending/flushing the payload, but the request still doesn't complete until the action method is completed.

Would it work to do the logging in a middleware?

EDIT:

One workaround that I found was to use [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) like this:

```
JobManager.Initialize(new Registry());
JobManager.Start();
```

in Program.cs before host.Run() and then schedule an immediate task from an action like this:

```
JobManager.AddJob(() =>
{
    // do something...
}, (s) => s.ToRunOnceIn(1).Seconds());
```

Comment: It's a bit to broad, without knowing if you use any message brokers/buses or see the specific code. Maybe post some code of whatever you are using. The most straight-forward way would be to use a message bus and just fire up an event and have it logged later

Comment: I'm not using any kind of queuing system. I am hoping there is something in the framework to support this.

Comment: Response.OnCompleted comes close, but the connection is still open when that runs.

Comment: Also are you sure this causes performance issues for you? Just because it takes 10 ms doesn't mean, your server will be capped at 100 connections/second. When an async call is being processed the request thread is returned to the pool and available for other requests. Once the async operation finishes, it takes the next available thread to finish the request. So have you done any performance measurement to determine if that's an issue at all or not

Comment: Yes. I have a benchmark set up. If I disable the logging it takes less than 1ms; if I turn it back on it jumps to 10s. I am not so much interested in being able to sustain many concurrent requests, but rather that each request to be as quick as possible (I'm using lots of caching to make this happen; for the <1ms case I'm not going to the database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start somehow a different thread. A middleware put in front of the pipeline will give you the chance to do work just before the request completes. If you spin a thread, from there, then it might work.

You probably want to use some sort of [producer-consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) so you don't kill your server. Otherwise, if every request starts a thread that does work immediately and you have many requests at the same time, you might end up running out of resources. A producer-consumer would help you throttle that work.

If you're not in a hurry, you can wait another week or so when I'll deliver the file logger for ASP.NET and then you'll see a similar implementation there.

Comment: Didn't you guys from Microsoft always told us not to start our own threads within ASP.NET (guess it should apply to ASP.NET Core too), because it messes up with the way ASP.NET manages it's thread pool for handing async requests?

Comment: If you use a producer consumer you shouldn't need to spin new threads for every request.

Comment: Frameworks like Quarts.NET, FluentScheduler, and HangFire seem to work by starting threads. However, they're not supporting Core just yet from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Logging in middleware won't help you, as you will still be within the request pipeline and you may or may not have the necessary information to log what you need to do.

You could log asynchronously, which would probably give you the biggest improvement without major architectural changes:  [Async Programming : Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1030252/Multithreading-in-Csharp-NET-Part)

If that doesn't work, you can do something that is multithreaded.  That gets more complicated, but it is still doable: [Multithreading in C# .NET 4.5 (Part 1)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1030252/Multithreading-in-Csharp-NET-Part)

Comment: I was hoping there would be a hook for "after the pipeline finished"... Response.OnCompleted gets close, but the connected is still open and the calling party still waits for me to do the processing in OnCompleted.

Comment: I think the problem that you would have with this approach is that it is still a part of the pipeline, which means it would slow down your overall response.  I don't think it would really buy you anything unless you introduced some asynchronous or multithreading methods.

Comment: If I could hook into the pipeline AFTER the request finishes, i.e. after the API caller gets the full response, then from the outside world's perspective it would look like the request took under 1ms. Yes, if the server is under a lot of pressure the overall rate would increase from 1ms, but those cases are rare. There are plenty of CPU cores doing nothing most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Async is the correct way to solve this problem.  During your request (whenever you want) *start* an async connection/query to the database.  Just don't wait for it to finish.

Comment: ASP.NET Core uses dependency injection and some services are scoped, which means they only have a lifetime which is equal of that one of the request and get disposed at the end. I dunno on top of my head how it behaves with the `ILogger<T>` implementation. Are you **certain** it's not scoped? Otherwise this solution won't work as there is a chance that it get disposed before it's finished (if the request is significantly faster than the logging operations)

Comment: Oops, this was supposed to be a comment on the other answer.  Good point on the scoping though, I didn't consider interactions with such resources.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `HttpResponse.RegisterForDispose()`?  For example:

```
public class JobToRunAfterRequestIsComplete : IDisposable {
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do your post-processing here.
    } 
}

public class YourController {
    public void YourAction() {
        // Do your normal processing here
        ...
        // Register your post processing here
        this.Response.RegisterForDispose(new JobToRunAfterRequestIsComplete ());
    }
}
```