# in asp.net core, whether possible for the endpoint to process new requests before old requests completed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

**I test concurrency like this: Open 2 tabs in Chrome and visit localhost:5006/test almost simultaneously.

I want to achieve that I send 2 requests almost simultaneously and then getting 2 responses almost simultaneously 10 seconds later, but in reality I send 2 requests almost simultaneously and get the first response 10 seconds later, and then get the second response another 10 seconds**

I have tried using asynchronous endpoint but it doesn't work.
Here is my code.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**TestController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Test.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("/test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Echo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new requests come");
        await Task.Delay(10000); //Time-consuming operations
        return Ok("Hello");
    }
}
```

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62699",
      "sslPort": 44389
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5006",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What host process are you using?

Comment: How are you testing concurrency? Are you debugging with a breakpoint in the controller? [IIS proper](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit) is throttled to a handful of concurrent requests (but not 1) on low end OS's like Windows Home, but IIS Express shouldn't be.

Comment: I found a post that may some relative to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293643/processing-after-the-request-was-completed)